# \mapsto not works in mathabx

Tags: mathabx

Why $\mapsto$ not work in mathabx?
With the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\mapsto$
\end{document}
```

I have 
 [image]

without the "tail" of the arrow.

but, I need [image]

How I can fix this?
Ask this as I need $ f\mapsto g$ to display correctly and at the same time I also need $ \widecheck{f} $ correctly (for this I need to use mathabx)

Comment: Why do you just write `usepackage` instead of `\usepackage`?

Comment: Sorry, a mistake

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. If I compile your file (with `\usepackage` instead of `usepackage`), I get the correct symbol.

Comment: I need the arrow with a tail...

Comment: And that is exactly what I get. Otherwise, I would not have written that “I get the correct symbol”, right?!

Comment: How strange. The wrong symbol appears on my computer :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105829/discussion-between-eraldcoil-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Comment: Post the log of the compilation of this exact example